# MagicalRecord using

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm new to CoreData and MR. Trying to save some entities and read them after.

saving:

```
Events *newEvent = [Events MR_createEntity];
newEvent.title = @"qwe";
newEvent.date = [NSDate date];
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError * _Nullable error) {}];
```

reading:

```
NSMutableArray *events = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[Events MR_findAll]];
NSLog(@"%@",events);
```

as result I'm getting "data: < fault >"

if I add private context like:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_newPrivateQueueContext];
NSMutableArray *events = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[Events MR_findAllInContext:context]];
```

my app crashes with error reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'Events''

Can someone show me code working for my task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add any private context for this (if you don't need it for other reasons, obvious). The `"data: <fault>"` is part of the iOS. Core Data doesn't extract the information of an object if they are not directly accessed, this is a good choice for performance reasons. So, if you want to print in console your array, you have to cycle it and print every single element extracting it from the array.

```
for (Event *event in [Events MR_findAll]) {
    NSLog(@"Event name : %@", event.name)
}
```

This should work good.

PS: A little advice, **use singular names for your entities** because they represent a single object, a single class. Don't think at them as tables because they are not.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but this code still output data faults, 
nevertheless i can print event properties in this cycle